# Not only... but also

Tags: phrases, word-order

Consider the following:

> 1. Not only you should be able to speak but also able to write.
> 2. You should be able to not only speak but also write.
> 3. You should not only be able to speak but also be able to write.

Which is right to use? If there's an even better one, please suggest.

Comment: I would substitute "You should be able not only to speak but to write."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second and third sentences are correct:

> - You should be able to not only speak[,] but also write.
> - You should not only be able to speak[,] but also be able to write.

I would correct the first sentence thus:

> - Not only should you be able to speak[,] but also should you be able to write. *OR*
> - Not only should you be able to speak[,] but you should also be able to write.

I leave it to you to decide whether you want a comma before *but*. Either way is fine.

Comment: I would phrase your correction of the first sentence as "Not only should you be able to speak, but (you should) also (be able to) write", where the terms in parentheses are optional. It sounds odd to me to say "but also should you".

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Indeed it sounds odd. I wasn't really thinking about it being spoken, but then, I think that sentence would be the least frequently used of the three. I guess I was also trying to be symmetric, but I'll add the second option, as you suggested. However, I disagree that the words you parenthesized are optional.

Comment: @Jimi Oke: Eh, it's probably a matter of dialect or style or something. You know how English is.

Comment: "To not only speak" is, of course, a split infinitive, which some will take exception to...

Comment: @Jon Purdy, @Jimi Oke: I would have said: "Not only should you be able to speak, but (you should) also (be able) to write", which sounds far more natural to me (British).

Comment: @Brian Nixon: Some people do make a lot of unnecessary fuss about split infinitives, but in this case I'd be inclined to agree with them: to me, "You should be able not only to speak, but also to write" sounds much better, not so much because of the split infinitive, but because it brings out the parallelism between "to speak"/"to write" much more clearly.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Indeed, it is. @psmears: I rarely use the *not only…but also* construction in speech, much less begin a sentence with *Not only...*. Thus, you all are probably right about what sounds most natural. However, I got the distinct impression that the asker's examples were from a written context...

Comment: @Jimi Oke: I meant "said" in a general sense - I would write the same as well :) In my experience it's the sort of expression people tend to use in speech only when they're telling someone off ("Not only have you forgotten to do your homework, but you are also scruffily dressed!").